# Tesseract 3.02 Failed to find library "liblept172.dll" error in website

Tags: c#, dll, tesseract

My setup is a little complex:

a) I include the Tesseract 3.02 DLL in a DLL that uses it (ScanDoc.dll);

b) I include ScanDoc.dll in a Console Application;

c) I include ScanDoc.dll in a Website MVC Application.

What's weird is b works fine, but for c I keep getting:

> System.DllNotFoundException: Failed to find library "liblept172.dll" for platform x86.

---

For both b and c, the relative paths from my DLL to the x86 and x64 folder are the same for the Console and the Web Application's bin folder:

b) Console: tessdata, x64 and x86 are found in the same directory as my ScanDoc.dll

c) Website: tessdata, x64 and x86 are found in the same directory as my ScanDoc.dll

---

Further:

a) ScanDoc.dll: tessdata, x64 and x86 are found in the same directory as my ScanDoc.dll

I am building all in debug mode on the same machine (64-bit).  Also:

- tessdata folder contains: eng.traineddata
- x64 folder contains: liblept172.dll, libtesseract304.dll
- x86 folder contains: liblept172.dll, libtesseract304.dll

Any thoughts why website usage of said DLL would cause this error but not console application usage?  (I tried varying the build configuration between Any CPU/64/86 to no avail.)

Comment: Does it give the expected location of the DLL along with the exception? In case of website, are those DLL's placed under the bin directory?

Comment: No it doesn't give the expected location, nor does the diagnostic config recommended debugging write anything to the file (though it does create it).  Yes, the DLL and the x86/x64 folders are inside the website bin folder.

Comment: Can you debug the web application locally to see if it works fine on your machine?

Comment: Yeah unfortunately it doesn't tell me a lot.  If I walk the code, no matter how I populate the directory, I get the same error when it hits here inside the ScanDoc.dll:

    using (var tessEngine = new TesseractEngine(tessdataDirectory, "eng", EngineMode.TesseractOnly))